# C# - Short form of null check and assignment in one line

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering if there's a shorter way to write something like this:

```
var element = Data.GetElement();
if (element != null) element.IsSelected = true;
```

In a way like this or similar in one line of code:

```
Data.GetElement()?.IsSelected = true;
```

Comment: And what error does `Data.GetElement()?.IsSelected = true;` cause?

Comment: Both codes look equivalent. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: When `Data.GetElement()?.IsSelected` is `null` (due to `Data.GetElement() == null`) you *can't assign* anything to `null`

Comment: Code `Data.GetElement()?.IsSelected = true;` will not compile because of the error: "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer"

Comment: You can simplify if you can change assignment to method call, assuming that you have a method `Select`  you can put `Data.GetElement()?.Select(true);`

Comment: If `element` is null there's no property to set. This isn't about finding a shorter way. The second snippet is trying to do something clearly wrong

Comment: I found some shorter form `if (Data.GetElement() is { } el) el.IsSelected = true; `

Comment: Just write a method and call it in one line

Comment: Making "smart" changes to code perfectly working and clear to understand is a recipe for future disasters.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when `Data.GetElement()` is `null` then `Data.GetElement()?.IsSelected` is `null` as well and we can't assign anything to `null`

```
null = true; // doesn't compile
```

That's why

```
Data.GetElement()?.IsSelected = true;
```

will not compile ("left-hand side can't be assigned ..."). However, if you insist on some shorter form, you can call a method. If there's a method `Select(bool isSelected)` you can put

```
Data.GetElement()?.Select(true);
```

If there's no such method you can implement it as an extension one:

```
public static class MyElementExtensions {
  //TODO: put the right type instead of MyElement
  public static bool Select(this MyElement dataElement, bool isSelected) {
    dataElement.IsSelected = isSelected;
  }
}
```

Comment: If `IsSelected` is a property, can I call a setter of it like a method?

Comment: @Dmitrii Sannikov: technically you can call setter as a method (with a help of Reflection), but I doubt if you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found some shorter form:

```
if (Data.GetElement() is { } el) el.IsSelected = true;
```